# Hibernate Exception during deploy

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, vaadin

I´m using hibernate 4.3.6 in my vaadin project. 
Every time I make changes in the sources code, it is expected that the application builds again and the new source code is deployed automatically to Tomcat. In other words, Tomcat should reload its context.

The problem is that during this operation hibernate throws an error:

```
GRAVE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
org.hibernate.HibernateException: registry does not contain entity manager factory: myproject
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry.getNamedEntityManagerFactory
(...)
```

After that log, i get:

```
24/09/2014 13:14:43 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/myproject] is completed
```

However, I cannot continue using the website, since I receive a message saying that session is lost.

My question is: what is this hibernate exception and how can I solve it?

EDIT:
This error only happens when I store in session a JPA Entity, for example: the logged user

Comment: if you stop and restart tomcat, the error still appears?

Comment: are you using hibernate with or without JPA? what version of vaadin your project is using?

Comment: HIbernate 4.3.6, Vaadin JPAContainer 3.1.1, Vaadin 7.3.1

Comment: Please add your hibernate / jpa configuration to your question. Any change to the source code produces this error or just some specific kind of change (for example: changes in some mapped entities in JPA)?

Comment: Any changes in the source code will produce this error, not only in JPA configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61851/discussion-between-marcelo-bezerra-and-guilhermecgs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t know any way to get what you want, in Tomcat, except with JRebel. The staff of Vaadin itself uses and recommends. Link with interesting information about Vaadin+JRebel: http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/jrebel-case-study-vaadin-eliminates-redeploys-and-saves-10-of-development-time/

If in the future you decide to use Jetty instead of Tomcat, you can make settings and get dynamic reloading of the application as suggested here: https://blog.oio.de/2012/08/23/dynamic-reloading-of-vaadin-applications-with-maven-and-eclipse /